# Grab All IDs Collected in MAP and set the IDs on each record in MAP per Collection

Tags: apex

I have code to go through matching Contacts by email address, and set/synch the Email Opt Out flag on each based on it being set on one.
So if Contact A, B, C have matching email, if Contact A EmailOptOut is set to TRUE, then it is also set to TRUE on Contacts B and C.

Yes, de-duplication is a goal here, hence my reasoning for this question:

When Contact A is updated, I have code to collect all matching contacts by email in a MAP.  HOW then can I, when updating Contact A, set the IDs of Contact A, B, and C in a field; and then on Contact B, set the IDs of Contact A, B, and C; and the same on Contact C?

```
for(Contact ContactListUpdates : [SELECT ID, Email, HasOptedOutOfEmail, DoNotCall, 
                                               Email_Opt_Out_Flagged__c, Do_Not_Call_Flagged__c, DupContactIDs__c 
                                               FROM Contact where Email in :newContactMap.keySet()]) 
    { 
        contactsMap.put(ContactListUpdates.ID, ContactListUpdates);
        system.debug('Con ---' + ContactListUpdates.ID + ' -- collecting -- ' + ContactListUpdates.Email);    
        system.debug('Con --- Collection Query run  '+ contactsMap.keySet());                      
    }
```

BY the end of this loop, I have a collection of all Contact records to update matched to the first record that triggered the update.  The contactsMap.keySet() looks like:

```
10:40:54:159 USER_DEBUG [101]|DEBUG|Con --- Collection Query run  {0030R00000HFuGcQAL, 0030R00000MMZ3HQAX, 003F000002ISZKWIA5, 003F000002J5mXMIAZ}
```

This collection is the first ID, and the matching other 3 IDs to update.  I want this exact output saved in each record's "DupContactIDs__c" field.  How can I do this?  Started braingstorming with the below:

```
Map<ID, Contact> contactsMap = new Map<ID, Contact >();
Map<ID, String> DupContactMap = new Map<ID, String>();

for (ID CID : contactsMap.keyset())
    {
        Contact ContactDupList = contactsMap.get(CID);
        DupContactMap.put(ContactDupList.ID, contactsMap.keySet());   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to match on email, so the map would look like this:

```
Map<String, Set<Id>> contactsByEmail = new Map<String, Set<Id>>();
```

Which you'd populate in your loop:

```
for(Contact ContactListUpdates: ...) {
  Set<Id> relatedContacts = contactsByEmail.get(ContactListUpdates.email);
  if(relatedContacts == null) {
    contactsByEmail.put(ContactListUpdates.Email, relatedContacts = new Set<Id>());
  }
  relatedContacts.add(ContactListUpdates.Id);
}
```

At this point, you'd loop over the contacts again and populate the appropriate field, something like:

```
for(Contact record: contactsMap.values()) {
  record.DupContactIDs__c = String.join(new List<Id>(contactsByEmail.get(record.Email)),',');
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  However for the last line (record.DupContactsIDs__c .... I get the error: Invalid initializer type Set<Id> found for List<String>: expected an Integer or a List of type String

Comment: @dannycheeko Yeah, I didn't specifically test this; it should have been `new List<Id>` instead.